# Android TimeStamp not working correctly

Tags: android, timestamp

So i am basically trying to implement a timestamp.

I believe i have the correct code but the time i get from the timestamp is 1 Jan 1970 all the time.

How do i make it so it retrieves the device time on their clock?

I was sure this would work when reading android documentation but no clue whats wrong?

I believe the issue is with the below code:

```
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        textView.setText(DateUtils
                .getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe i have the correct code but the time i get from the timestamp is 1 Jan 1970 all the time

Presumably, `timestamp` is `0`.

> How do i make it so it retrieves the device time on their clock?

Pass in `System.currentTimeMillis()`, instead of `0`.